# Moved .mov to wrong directory and now it is a Unix Executable File

Tags: linux, mv

Was moving a movie file using `mv` but I typed the directory wrong. It turned my movie file into a Unix Executable File.

`mv /path/to/folder/1/this.mov /path/to/folder2`

`/folder2` did not exist

Can I undo this action or return this file to a .mov?

I fear that this is not an undo thing. Any help or guidance will be a great thing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is now `/path/to/folder2`. Just rename it:

```
mv /path/to/folder2 /path/to/this.mov
```

to keep it in where it is currently.

To move it back to `/path/to/folder/1/`:

```
mv /path/to/folder2 /path/to/folder/1/this.mov
```